# Google Publishing Tags allow the client to edit update adverts

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, double-click-advertising, google-publisher-tag

Hi I am trying to embed GPT (Google Publishing Tags) adverts into my web application (which work fine).  However I have been asked to ensure that the client can edit and amend the GPT HTML scriptlets reviewing there changes prior to sending there changes live. My problem is that when I reinsert the amended advertising HTML and  Scripts back into the DOM (for review) the advert scripts no longer are able to be executed by the browser (javascript error).

Hi I have tried looking through the following sites for help: https://support.google.com/admanager#topic=7505988

As well as trying various things mentioned in the GPT API reference such as destroySlots option for example so I can reset the googletag javascript object to reinsert the script
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference

Please review this minimal reproducible example of what I want to achieve: 
https://codepen.io/angusgrant/pen/eawbLV

1. Click on 'Edit Advert' button (A dialog window should open with a textarea input showing a HTML textarea input with the HTML source of the advert script shown.
2. Click on 'Preview' button. Note that the GPT advert no longer is displayed / rendered.

This is the HTML (scriptlet) I am loading on page load and need to be able to reinsert back into the DOM via JS:

```html
<div id="addSlot1" style="height:600px; width:160px;">
    <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function()
    {
    googletag.defineSlot('/1008130/Wide_Skyscrape', [160, 600], 'addSlot1')
    .addService(googletag.pubads())
    .setTargeting("Pub_code", "asnr");
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display('addSlot1');
    });
    </script>
  </div>
```

I expect the advert to be (still) displayed (with any amendment to the HTML made in the textarea being rendered in the web page as well).

What I actually experience is that the advert code gets loaded into the DOM  as expected (with exactly the same HTML/ Javascript code) and the browser tries to render changes but I get an error in the developer tools:

```
Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read property 'addService' of null
```

and the advert no longer renders.

[image]

Please advise how I re-write the GPT HTML / scriptlet so it runs on page load and when reinserted back into the DOM ?

Comment: how you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Hi Sam no i never did this is just a known issue and clients have to wait for a total reload  to view the amended adverts on the site.